# Laravel Eloquent: Any way to get the original relation of a changed model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saved(function (Topic $topic) {
            if ($topic->wasChanged('category_id')) {
                $topic->category->updateItemCount();
                // $topic->orignalCategory->updateItemCount(); !!!
            }

        });
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function updateItemCount()
    {
        $this->item_count = $this->items()->count();
        $this->save();
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

When I saved an item model, I have to update the item_count of both the original category and the current category. Is there any elegant way to get the orignalCategory?

Answer (score 0):

Try using saving instead of saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `saving()`:

```php
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function (Topic $topic) {
            // $currentCategory contains the currently assigned category before saving.
            $currentCategory = $topic->category;

            $currentCategoryId = $topic->getOriginal('category_id');

            if ($topic->isDirty('category_id')) {
                // $newId now contains the category_id, about to be saved to the model.
                $newId = $topic->category_id;

                // If you want to change the new category, you should retrieve it manually
                // here using `Category::find($topic->category_id)`,
                // or use the `static::saved()` method which should have the updated relation.
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for a model Observer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers
You can use the updated() event for this.